# While configuring dot cover in VSTS, Unable to find the TargetArguments path

Tags: devops, azure-pipelines

I have installed Resharper command line in my build server, and I added command line task in my VSTS build profile like below:

[Build profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1RiI.png)

In my project, we are using xUnit test project, so here my main concern is with target executable path. I tried installing xUnit as it is VS extension. But how can I use xUnit as target executable?

Following is the command line I want to use:

```
dotcover analyse  /TargetExecutable={Path to Xunit}"   /TargetArguments= $(Build.SourcesDirectory)+"\xxxxxx.AD.UnitTest\bin\Release\VonExpy.AD.UnitTest.dll"   /Output="AppCoverageReport.html"   /ReportType="HTML"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding unable to find the TargetArguments path issue, the value of TargetArguments parameter is incorrect, change it to

`/TargetArguments="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\xxxxxx.AD.UnitTest\bin\Release\VonExpy.AD.UnitTest.dll"`

Regarding xUnit test, based on this thread: [Error encountered when running dotcover console runner using xunit as the target executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877281/error-encountered-when-running-dotcover-console-runner-using-xunit-as-the-target), you need to use xunit.console.exe in [xunit.runner.console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.console) package.